# Generalised Triangle Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

For $x, y, z\in\mathbb{R}$ and usual absolute value, we have the following form of the triangle inequality:
$$
|x+y|\ge|x|-|y|
$$
What I want is a generalised form like:
$$
|x+y_1+\cdots+y_n|\ge |x|-\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|
$$
But I don't know for sure if it's true, and I'm stuck with proving it. I tried generalising the first formula for $y = y_1 +\cdots+y_n$ but getting nowhere. Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: It is always true!

Comment: The real inequality is slightly stronger: $\;|x-y|\ge\bigl||x|-|y|\bigr|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite $x$ to $x=x+\sum y_i-\sum y_i$, then $|x|\leq |x+\sum y_i|+|\sum y_i|\leq |x+\sum y_i|+\sum| y_i|$ and you obtain your inequality.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}|x| &= \left| x + \sum_{i=1}^n y_i - \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right| \\&\leq \left| x + \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \right| + \left| \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right| \\&\leq \left| x + \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \right| +  \sum_{i=1}^n \left|y_i\right|\end{align}